# jquery function doesn't work after ajax call back

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I am using asp.net 3.5

I have a jquery function that works fine on 'hover' event .

problem occurs after a the browser refresh some div's 
using an ajax call .

from that point browser ignore 
the hover event and doesn't call the jquery function.
it goes back normal only after page is refresh.

*** to make ajax call's i am using**

> ```
> <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4"  runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
>          <ContentTemplate runat="server">
>             <div id='map' runat="server"></div>                        
>           </ContentTemplate>
>  </asp:UpdatePanel>
> ```

**-- this is the jquery function --**

```
$(function() {
  $('a.trigger').hover(function() {

    var index = $(".trigger").index(this);

  var pop=document.getElementById("pop_up");

  var place=document.getElementsByClassName('place')[index ];

  var car_id=document.getElementsByClassName('car_id')[index];
  var enter_time=document.getElementsByClassName('time')[index ];
  pop.innerHTML="Park At: "+place.innerHTML+"</br>Car Id:"+car_id.innerHTML+"</br>Enter At:"+enter_time.innerHTML;

    $('div#pop_up').show();
  }, function() {
    $('div#pop_up').hide();
  });
});
```

-- this is div that doesn't response after ajax call back --

> ```
> <div id="pop_up" runat="server">
>     <p  id='who_parks_here' runat="server"></p>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: try replace `$('a.trigger').hover(function() {` with `$('a.trigger').live("hover", function() {`

Comment: `on` or `live` will help

Comment: The `.live()` function has been deprecated for months, **nobody** should be writing new code that uses it. Use `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.on()` as ASP.NET AJAX call removes the already attached event handlers when new HTML is received in the AJAX panel.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('hover', 'a.trigger', function() {

        var index = $(".trigger").index(this);

        var pop = document.getElementById("pop_up");

        var place = document.getElementsByClassName('place')[index];

        var car_id = document.getElementsByClassName('car_id')[index];
        var enter_time = document.getElementsByClassName('time')[index];
        pop.innerHTML = "Park At: " + place.innerHTML + "</br>Car Id:" + car_id.innerHTML + "</br>Enter At:" + enter_time.innerHTML;

        $('div#pop_up').show();
    }, function() {
        $('div#pop_up').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you need to bind separate handlers to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events when using `.on()`, since `hover` isn't an actual event; the `.hover()` function is just a shortcut jQuery provides for binding handlers to those two events.

Comment: It would be better to use $('#pop_up') than $(document)

Comment: @Jack: Hovering over a link displays the `<div>` element with an ID of `pop_up`, so I don't think those links are **inside** that element. Without seeing actual HTML there's absolutely no way to know what element should be used in place of `document`.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Hmm that's true, the original selector wasn't contained either :)